# Due to SelectIO banking constraints, the IOBs in your design cannot be automatically placed

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I'm using Spartan 3E starter kit. In creating a custom peripheral. I use the default settings except interfacing it to the PLB bus. I also generated XISE project. I added my ports which only consists of:

```
    phy_tx_data : out std_logic_vector (0 to 3);
    phy_tx_en   : out std_logic;
    phy_tx_clk  : in std_logic;
    phy_crs     : in std_logic;
```

That is only but a few ports but the IOBs exceeded the limit of the available resources after synthesizing my ethernet transmit module. I would want to know how to actually implement it in the FPGA. Does the IOBs pertains to the ports of the top-level module? If so, I just added a few ports and it already exceeded. Why is that so? How can I overcome it? It seemed that the plb slave module consumed most of the available ports.. Or does the IOBs pertain to all signals and registers.. I really need help here.

Comment: If you are using ISE version prior to 13, then this was an undocumented unpleasant and nasty bug that Xilinx keep refusing to admit it, but it was fixed in the later version of their tool. What is the version of your ISE?

Comment: 14.6 is the version of my ise

Comment: Is your PLB also brought out as toplevel ports also?

Comment: Well, it sound like the old bug is back in the new release as well. The problem with the ISE was if you do not declare the signals on an instantiated IP, it would aromatically take them up to the top level and declare them as IOs. In order to solve this, you should declare a dummy signal, connect it to all the ports that are not used and leave it hanging, that way, they will be optimized during the synthesis and P&R and you will not get this error message. But if you have those signals on top level, you must optimize your design.

Answer (score 0):

IOB = physical IO pin.  You can't put a design on an FPGA that requires more physical pins than the FPGA package provides.  There are two solutions to this: either get a bigger FPGA or use fewer IO pins.